# Dynamically modifying an object

Tags: reactjs

I have a form used to upload some files right now.
I wish that the user would input a number corresponding to the inputted value

Right now, I have an object containing an hard-coded list of documents categories to upload:

```
const files= {
    BIRTH_CERTIFICATE: values.files.BIRTH_CERTIFICATE,
    RESUME: values.files.RESUME,
};
```

In my case, it is possible that a user will have to upload a varying number of a same category of document. I would like to append these to the already existing files object and have something like :

```
const files= {
    BIRTH_CERTIFICATE: values.files.BIRTH_CERTIFICATE,
    RESUME: values.files.RESUME,
    CHILDREN_BIRTH_CERTIFICATE_1: values.files.CHILDREN_BIRTH_CERTIFICATE_1,
    CHILDREN_BIRTH_CERTIFICATE_2: values.files.CHILDREN_BIRTH_CERTIFICATE_2,
    CHILDREN_BIRTH_CERTIFICATE_3: values.files.CHILDREN_BIRTH_CERTIFICATE_3,
};
```

The number of children would be contained in a variable named childrenCount for example

Thanks for reading :D

Comment: You used the `reactjs` tag, is this data stored as some state or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use template literals for the above. Whenever a new file is uploaded, you can do

```
files[`CHILDREN_BIRTH_CERTIFICATE_${childrenCount}`] = inputFile
childrenCount += 1
```

You can read about [template literals](https://www.programiz.com/javascript/template-literal) to get a better understanding.